# Why fileobject and fileobject.readlines() give same result in Python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this Python Code and don't know if this is how it is supposed to behave

```
    def main():
        fh = open('metallica_lyrics.txt')
        for line in fh.readlines():
            print(line,end='')
```

And

```
    def main():
        fh = open('metallica_lyrics.txt')
        for line in fh:
            print(line,end='')
```

give me the same result. Does the readlines() have no effect on the file object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `readlines()` function will read in the entire file, splitting it on newlines and storing it in a list. You can use it outside of `for` to create a list easily, which you can't do with the file object by itself. It's just that iterating over it has the exact same effect as iterating over the file object itself, either by cool design coincidence or smart language design (or both). When you iterate over a list, you take one item out at a time. In the case of `for line in fh.readlines()`, you're iterating over a list that's extracted from the file object, and it just so happens that each item in the list is a line from the file.

The behavior of `for line in fh` is just a cool design quirk of Python, to make programming easier. However, if you do it that way, you won't be storing all the lines in memory like `readlines()` would do. That's probably the better option just for the sake of memory optimization.

Comment: So is the second style of writing Python a step towards writing faster and optimized python code? If so, I might as well put this into practice early on. Thanks.